kubernetes release name for a Job instance still in use even after ttlAfterFinished is long due
I use helm to schedule jobs (not CronJobs, just Jobs). I use the ttlAfterFinished to remove them automatically after they are finished. But when I come back and try to shedule the same job again with helm, it tells me that the release name is already in use.
My question is: "What the heck?"
Why is a job release name still in use, when the job finished a week ago and the ttlAfterFinished was set to 8 hours?
EDIT: It has been pointed out, that the installed helmcharts are stored somewhere else. So, how do I make the Job cleanup after itself completely when using helm install? Is it possible?

Helm is telling you that the release job is already in use? Are you using an helm install with the same release name? That is expected, cleaning the job does not clean the fact that you installed the helm chart, that is stored in secrets unrelated to the job. Instead of helm install, just use helm upgrade --install if that is the case. If instead you are talking about the actual job being still there in the cluster after its time to live has expired, what's its status? Might be in terminating because it has a finalizer preventing its destruction (time to live honors finalizers)

You're getting this complaint from Helm, not plain Kubernetes.  When you helm install something, Helm keeps track of what it's installed with what settings; you can helm list the installed Helm releases, and for each of those helm get values with their configuration settings and helm get manifest to get the Kubernetes objects that Helm installed.
So say you helm install some-release-name ./chart to install a chart that happens to include a single Job with a setting to delete itself.  Even if the Job object is gone from the cluster, the Helm release is still around, and helm get manifest some-release-name will show you what the Job looked like.  Because the Helm release already exists, re-running helm install will produce an error.
The easy answer here is to helm upgrade --install instead.  On a normal chart that would compare what's in the chart with its current values with what's in the cluster, and push out an update; in this case, it will reïnstall the Job (verified with Helm 3.16.1).  If the chart isn't installed at all, then it will install it just like helm install does.

Compare Can I use helm for fire and forget k8s Jobs?; my answer to that uses helm upgrade --install for exactly this reason.  For this use case you don't necessarily want Helm's history features, and just kubectl applying the Job might be better.

So, if I want to fire and forget k8s Jobs? I may NOT use helm and I have to use kubectl directly?

As I say in the other answer, Helm does work for this case, up to the point of it keeping history you don't care about.  The asker in that question wanted to use Helm everywhere for consistency, and you might want to use Helm templating with a known set of values for things like image tags and other settings.
